# dbatools Invoke-DbaQuery truncates results at 90 characters

Tags: dbatools

I'm using Invoke-DbaQuery to spool current application settings to a text file ahead of an application refresh but see the output is truncated at 90 characters.  Does anyone know how to get past this limitation?

Comment: The old Invoke-SqlCmd had a "-MaxCharLength" parameter but that doesn't work with Invoke-DbaQuery.

Comment: Piping to "Format-Table -Autosize" also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Piping the output to "Out-String -Width 200" fixes this issue.